# How should spades be attached to high voltage wiring?

Tags: electrical

I am adding a [ICM102](https://www.icmcontrols.com/product/icm102/) delay-on-make relay to a circulation pump. It's rated for 110AC voltage, but how should I transition from the solid copper 12awg into and out of this device?

I can naively just crimp the spade in like I might any other low voltage line, but I'm not sure that's correct and I haven't done very many of these.

I'm considering making or buying 12awg stranded pigtails and then wire-nutting the pigtails to the solid wire

Comment: If the crimps are done right, they should work, but pre-made crimps with pigtails might be easier.  Loose/badly crimp work will cause heat, that might damage relay or worst.  Are you a good crimper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crimps suitable for solid wire are available (eg Tyco 4-520448-2), but your plan to use pre-fabricated flex pigtails is also a valid alternative.

Comment: Fwiw I just discovered they make this exact relay with wire leads instead of spades l, so I'll just use that. Nonetheless your answer is valuable information!